# using location.hash as javascript postMessage fallback

Tags: javascript, url

I want to do cross domain messaging between an iframe and its parent. The new javascript postMessage api looks perfect and this [jquery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/) provides a fallback for older browsers by using location.hash. Now the message I want to pass is of a fairly large (approx 500 characters). Will there be any problems/issues with having a large location.hash value in the older browsers which don’t support the postMessage api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 and lower have known issues with URLs that are over 2,083 characters.  Providing you stay under this limit, you should be fine in all browsers.

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427

Comment: Do any of the other main browsers have lower limits? and what about IE6?

Comment: @Matt27: nope, not as far as I'm aware. IE 6 has the same limit. It is adjustable with a registry edit, but that doesn't help most web developers.